# MySQL gap locking

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a table called `tree_nodes`, in there I store a ... tree representation of my nodes. My topic tree is created in the context of a holder. So, there is a column called `holder_id`.

I have a transactional method that is doing several reads from this and other tables in order to determine what nodes should be added/removed from the tree.

My application is clustered and is highly concurrent, so, the in-app code mutexes not gonna work.

My relational DB is MySQL.

Here is what I wanted to do, I want to place a gap locking query to prevent concurrent modifications into that table.
From what I see most of those queries look like range queries or exact match queries. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_nodes where tree_node_id > some_value FOR UPDATE
```

The thing is that in my case the query will look like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tree_nodes where holder_id=? FOR UPDATE
```

But this might result in a large dataset being transferred from db into my app for no reason as I do not plan to work with all of those nodes.

Can I instead place the follwing query and expect locking to work as expected?

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM tree_nodes WHERE holder_id=? FOR UPDATE
```

=======UPDATE=======

Here is the behavior that I experience, I see that all threads stop as one of them acquires the lock, and then after it finishes it seems like a latch being removed and the rest of them start hitting without acquiring a lock, I have appended the information below about the transactions when the lock is being held on the first thread.

```
---TRANSACTION 7492, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 10, OS thread handle 123145553260544, query id 1290 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7491, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 11, OS thread handle 123145553575936, query id 1289 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7490, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 17, OS thread handle 123145555468288, query id 1287 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7489, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 15, OS thread handle 123145554837504, query id 1286 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7488, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 18, OS thread handle 123145555783680, query id 1285 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7487, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 12, OS thread handle 123145553891328, query id 1284 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7486, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 16, OS thread handle 123145555152896, query id 1282 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7485, ACTIVE 261 sec
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 9, OS thread handle 123145552945152, query id 1283 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485
```

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Why not use some other locking method, like [optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)?

Comment: It will still require some degree of locking, no?

Comment: Maybe, but if you want to avoid transfers and unnecessary overhead, optimistic locking might be the way to do it. This depends on how likely a collision is.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely an option. Something to consider.

Comment: In my experience using actual database locks is a recipe for disaster as at some point something will fail to release them properly and then all sorts of problems emerge. An optimistic lock is far less likely to experience such a catastrophic failure. Worst case you just get stuck trying and trying and trying to get a chance to commit, waiting for an opening.

Comment: There are risks of deadlocks for sure, but as long as there is a single entry point into the transaction (and that is the only transactional code that locks that table), should be fine

Comment: It is the where clause of the select statement that determines the locks being placed, not the select list. However, in this particular case @tadman's suggestion may work better depending on how long you want to hold the lock for. Btw, field = value condition is less likely to result in a gap lock.

Comment: @Shadow Surprisingly the query that I have above doesn't lock rows that are not yet inserted, so the gap lock does not work, I do not quite understand why

Comment: It's not really a surprise, why would a query using = operator lock any gaps?

Comment: How would you re-write it? I thought that it will lock everything that has the potential of falling into the range of possible values. And here, it is pretty much any value that has mentioned `holder_id` @Shadow

Comment: It locks existing records, but not gaps. I honestly don't understand what you are after here! Perhaps, you are mixing up various lock types!

Comment: Ok, I have tried this: `PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select count(*) from topic_nodes where id>'a' for update]; (conn=17) Deadlock found when trying to get lock;` Why the deadlock now... It is not when I am trying to insert, but when I try to acquire it..

Comment: @Shadow I want to get an exclusive lock so that my transactions see up to date data. How do I do that?

Comment: here is why it doesn't work:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95230&thanks=3&notify=195

Comment: The behaviour is in line with the documented behaviour. I also do not get why this is an issue. If you want gap lock on an interval, you need to specify an interval.

Comment: I did lock with the interval, exclusive lock was not set!

Comment: “A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads.” But in my testing I see that the lock is not exclusive, but shared when it comes down to gap locking. That bug above proves the behaviour that I experience.

Answer (score 0):

This the reason I wasn't able to achieve what I wanted:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95230